# Searching multiple word in a given column using regular expression in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql, search

I want to perform multiple word on particular column. The given search string may be in different order.  For example , I want to search the book name "Harry Potter Dream world "from books table using like operator and regular expression.

I know, using multiple like operator, we can perform operation using below query

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_1 
WHERE bookname LIKE 'Harry Potter' OR LIKE 'Heaven world'
```

In this case, I want to perform this in a single query. Also I tried with `FREETEXT` options. That wont be useful when i use self-join. Kindly provide me any other alternatives to solve this.

Also can you provide , how to use regular expression to search multiple word in SQL Server. I tried with multiple options. It won't work for me.

Comment: Please provide some test scenario... How should the query know what belongs together and what does not ("Harry Potter" won't be "Potter Harry" and you probably do not want to find "Dirty Harry" just because there's a "Harry" in there)? You must give more details, otherwise this will be closed quickly...

Comment: This is exactly like contains search. I mean, however the author is given, we need to bring all the records from DB. Either you can give Harry Potter or Potter Harry or World Dream or Dream World . etc. I want all the records which contains any one of the words or all the words.

Comment: Still not clear... But would you really like to find "Harry's Dream"? In your example **you** know, that "Harry Potter" and "Dream World" are two books, but **the poor query cannot know this**. What about "A Midsummer Night's Dream World of Warcraft". You want to find "Dream World" as well?

Comment: Hi, is this still open? Do you need further help?

Answer (score 1):

How about this one...

```
DECLARE @phrase nvarchar(max) = 'Harry Potter Dream world'

;WITH words AS (
    SELECT word = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
    FROM ( 
        SELECT x = 
            CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
                + REPLACE(@phrase, ' ', '</i><i>') 
                + '</i>').query('.')
    ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
)
SELECT * 
FROM 
    TABLE_1
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT found = 1 
        FROM words 
        WHERE bookname like '%' + word + '%') search
```

Comment: I was thinking of something similar, but this is far to greedy. Just imagine a search string like "About a boy". You would find all titles with an "a"... Still worth an upvote from my side...

Comment: Btw: Your CTE can be bit simpler. No need for `.query('.')`, no need for `.value('(./text())[1]')`. I'll poste an answer with a slightly simpler call...

Comment: Of course, everything you said is valid. I simply copy/pasted something from another guys solution and adapted the thing. I don't want to think what will it look like to search for "a" in a large table :D However, the reasonable optimisation would be to kick out everything shorter than 3-4 letters...

Comment: Yes,and now search for [this](http://www.amazon.de/Who-50-Die-offizielle-Bandgeschichte/dp/3791381873/ref=sr_1_6?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1459778379&sr=1-6&keywords=Who) Hrch Hrch Hrch ...

Answer (score 1):

Searching with `LIKE` could lead to very many hits, especially if you deal with a search string containing "the" or "a"...

The following code will first split your search string into its words, then split the book's names into the words and check for *full word hits*

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT, BookName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'Harry Potter')
,(2,'Dream world')
,(3,'A Midsumme Night''s Dream')
,(4,'Some other Book') --will not be found
,(5,'World of Warcraft');

DECLARE @phrase nvarchar(max) = 'Harry Potter o Dream world'

;WITH words AS (
    SELECT word = z.i.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
    FROM (SELECT CAST('<i>' + REPLACE(@phrase, ' ', '</i><i>') + '</i>' AS XML)) AS x(y)
    CROSS APPLY x.y.nodes('/i') AS z(i)
)
SELECT * 
FROM @tbl AS tbl
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM
    (
        SELECT z.i.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
        FROM (SELECT CAST('<i>' + REPLACE(tbl.BookName, ' ', '</i><i>') + '</i>' AS XML)) AS x(y)
        CROSS APPLY x.y.nodes('/i') AS z(i)
    ) AS checkWords(word)
    WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM words WHERE words.word=checkWords.word)
)
```